# Which preposition to use for the verb "croire" - en vs à?

Tags: grammaire, prépositions, verbes

I found the following sentence:

> Nous croyons à la paix universelle.

However, I'm not sure why this sentence uses *à* as its preposition and not *en*. In other sentences (which I don't have now, sorry), I found the verb *croire* uses *en* as its preposition.

But still, I'm not sure when to use one over the other. How can I use them apart correctly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The preposition to use depends on which one of the (slightly overlapping) meanings of *croire* you want to use.

- *Croire en...* means you trust something or someone, can be a faith.
- *Croire a...* means you believe that something or someone's existence is possible.

With your example, both forms are possible:

> *Je crois à la paix universelle*:

I believe universal peace is achievable.

> *Je crois en la paix universelle*:

Universal peace is one of my personal creeds.

See [Académie française](http://www.academie-francaise.fr/l-de-l-allemagne)

Answer (score 1):

The distinction between the two is rather difficult; let's compare the définitions in the TLFi.

> A. [Le complément est précédé de « à ».] Croire + à + subst. Être persuadé de quelque chose par adhésion de l'esprit, de manière rationnelle, mais aussi avec confiance.
>
> B. [Le complément est précédé de « en ».] Croire + en + subst. Apporter une adhésion totale mais personnelle, en y attachant une valeur éthique qui porte l'individu à se comporter en conséquence avec confiance et amour.

It is possible to say "croire à Dieu" et "croire en Dieu"; by means of the first form you are simply saying that you do not doubt the existence of the god of the christians. By means of the second  you express at the same time your belief in the existence of God and your feeling of confidence in the rightfulness, in the greatness of God. Translating the first into English you say "to believe in God" or "to believe in the existence of God"; however, for a translation of the second, if you do use this same form (which,  out of context, is rather ambiguous), you also say in a more distinct manner "to trust **in** God".

It is useful to review all the possible types of uses with the help of examples from the literature; the following, extracted from the TLFi, allows to do that.

***A*** THE MAIN TYPES OF USES FOR THE FIRST CASE

**1. [Le substantif désigne une personne.] Croire à qqn**

**a) Être persuadé de l'existence réelle de quelqu'un**

- Croire à Dieu, au diable _ ex : Il m'a même dit qu'il avait cru au diable avant de croire à Dieu.
- Certains ont cru aux anges, aux démons, aux génies.
- -- Et puis quand il va s'apercevoir que je me suis fichue de lui, dit Sylvaine, ça va être terrible!
  -- Oh! il a cru au gosse; il croira bien à une fausse couche.
- Croire au Père Noël [[meaning]] Être très naïf; se faire beaucoup d'illusions

**b) Croire à une catégorie de personnes, y ajouter foi; s'y fier**

- Croire aux astrologues, aux médecins.
- Ce qui lui manquait [à Manette] pour l'aimer [Coriolis], c'était d'y croire, d'avoir foi en lui.
- Ne te fie pas à la jeunesse, crois aux vieillards.
- Ce groupe met à sa tête un homme que j'estime comme particulier, auquel je ne crois pas comme homme politique

**2. [Le substantif désigne une chose.] Croire à qqc.**

**a) Penser que quelque chose a une existence réelle**

- Croire à l'âme, à l'immortalité
- Vous m'avez dit, mon Dieu, de croire à l'enfer
- Les plus grands esprits sont toujours des esprits sceptiques. Ils croient cependant à quelque chose : ils croient à tout ce qui peut les rendre plus grands. C'est le cas, par exemple, de Napoléon, qui croyait à son étoile, c'est-à-dire à soi-même. Or, ne pas croire aux croyances communes, c'est évidemment croire à soi, et souvent à soi seul...

  _ *Croire à qqc. dur comme fer*  [[meaning]] Y croire fermement, sans en démordre.
- Il [Leconte de Lisle] a cru dur comme fer à une Grèce qui n'a jamais existé que dans le cerveau de son ami [Louis Ménard].

**b) Avoir confiance en quelque chose**

- (not from TLFi) **Nous croyons à la paix universelle.**
- Croire à l'avenir, à la révolution
- Ah, messieurs! croyez à l'Assemblée de vos représentants.
- [Ils] ont cru aux dés.
- Car il [Brichot] avait cette curiosité, cette superstition de la vie, qui unie à un certain scepticisme relatif à l'objet de leurs études, donne dans n'importe quelle profession, à certains hommes intelligents, médecins qui ne croient pas à la médecine, professeurs de lycée qui ne croient pas au thème latin, la réputation d'esprits larges, brillants, et même supérieurs.
- ... vous êtes capable de mourir pour une idée, c'est visible à l'œil nu. Eh bien, moi, j'en ai assez des gens qui meurent pour une idée. Je ne crois pas à l'héroïsme, je sais que c'est facile et j'ai appris que c'était meurtrier. Ce qui m'intéresse, c'est qu'on vive et qu'on meure de ce qu'on aime.

_ *Veuillez croire à ..., je vous prie de croire à... (mes amitiés, mes sentiments)* Formule épistolaire de politesse.

- [Je] vous prie de croire, mon Général, à mes sentiments profondément et fidèlement dévoués.

**c) Penser qu'il peut s'agir de quelque chose; penser que quelque chose est probable**

- On ne peut rien dire encore (...). Je croirais à une fièvre cérébrale. L'excitation nerveuse est très intense.
- -- On peut l'avoir poussée, certes, mais sans lui donner de coups, sans qu'elle se défende...
  -- On ne l'a pas poussée.
  -- Vous croyez donc à l'accident?
- C'est à n'y pas croire.
- C'est inouï; ceci est si peu vraisemblable qu'il semble difficile à croire.

***B*** THE MAIN TYPES OF USES FOR THE SECOND CASE

**1. [Le substantif désigne une personne.] Croire en qqn. [[meaning]] avoir confiance en lui.**

- Pour aimer la gloire, il faut faire grand cas des hommes; il faut croire en eux.
- Vous avez perdu confiance, vous ne croyez plus en moi, on ne croit plus en moi, c'est ce qui me tue.
- La Ville-aux-Fayes croyait d'ailleurs en son Maire. La capacité de Gaubertin n'était pas moins prônée que sa probité, que son obligeance; il appartenait à ses parents, à ses administrés tout entier, mais à charge de revanche.

_ *Croire en Dieu* [[meaning]] Croire à son existence et avoir beaucoup d'amour et de confiance en Lui; avoir la foi

- À peine quelque préjugé est-il détruit par le tems, qu'on le voit remplacé par d'autres. Qu'y avons-nous gagné? Nous ne croyons plus en Dieu; mais nous croyons au diable : nous nous moquons des martyrs, et nous révérons les magiciens; nous rions des mystères, et nous redoutons les prestiges; nous jouons les esprits forts, et nous sommes des illuminés.

_ *Croire en soi*  [[meaning]] Être confiant en soi-même, en sa valeur, en son mérite, en ses possibilités

- Mais seraient-elles [les circonstances actuelles] un obstacle insurmontable si vraiment je croyais en moi avec la foi, avec l'illusion, de jadis?

**2. [Le substantif désigne une chose.] Croire en qqc. [[meaning]] avoir confiance en quelque chose**

- (not from TLFi) **Nous croyons en la paix universelle.**
- ... le temps pendant lequel tu auras cru en quelque fausse nouvelle t'aura grandement déterminé, car elle sera travail de graine et croissance de branches. Et ensuite, même si te voilà détrompé, tu seras autrement devenu.

Remarque : Noter également la forme « croire dans », contraction de « croire en le » ou, devant un nom plur., « croire en les ».

---

It can be noticed that in the examples found in the above the two prépositions, in certain cases, do not indicate a clear difference or even none at all (see the sections "A1b" and "B2").

This is corroborated by the French Academy's dictionary ;

> B. V. intr. 1. **Ajouter foi à un propos**
>   - Croire **au** rapport, **aux** déclarations de quelqu'un.
>   - Croire **à** des protestations d'innocence
>   _ *Croire **à** la parole de quelqu'un* [meaning] lui faire confiance, spécialement en pensant qu'il tiendra ses engagements.
>   - Croyez-vous **à** sa parole ? Personne ne croit plus à ses promesses. Bien m'en a pris, au milieu de ces difficultés, de croire **en** son jugement.
>   **2. Accorder de la valeur à quelque chose, concevoir de l'espoir à son sujet ; avoir confiance en la valeur de quelqu'un, mettre en lui de l'espoir**
>   - Il croyait **dans** les capacités de son ami, **à** son avenir. Elle croyait **en lui**.
>   _ *Croire en soi*

---

A personnal note on the use of the  prepositions "en" in place of "à" in "croire à la paix"

"Croire en la paix" is not really a possible moral stance as applied to a given conflict; of course, we'll have peace if the oppressed is subjugated, enslaved, and thus tamed, so to speak, causes no more blood spills; that is also peace; such peace, however, we can't believe in; what we can believe in is a particular sort of peace, a peace that'll be managed essentially in abidance by the rule of a fair treatment of grievances from all sides and which necessarily entails compromise from all parties.
Short of the context of a conflict it is not quite a serious moral stance as very few people in the World hold the opposite one and as those few that do are considered as more or less barbaric or mentally ill ; of course we are no barbarians. Even those ethnic groups given to waging war for reasons more or less justifiable "believe in peace"; war is only a means to achieve a more desirable peace and after war there must be peace, whatever its modalities.
What's left then in the way of something current in matters of asserting beliefs as regards peace by means of those two prepositions is whether we think or not that it is an attainable or preservable state. We can then say "Nous ne croyons pas à la paix au Proche Orient.", "Il commence à croire à la paix dans le monde." and so on. Elliptic forms become usual after the context is clear. "Croire à la paix" means then "to believe that peace can be attained" or "to believe that people will not resort to arms to solve their disputes".

Comment: À quel moment vous vous êtes dit que copier coller 75 lignes TLFI était une bonne idée ?

Comment: @TeleportingGoat La question concerne la possibilité de savoir quand utiliser l'une des prépositions plutôt que l'autre ; il me semble qu'il est important pour cela de comprendre le sens précis de « croire » pour décider assez facilement et il me semble aussi qu'il n'y a pas de meilleur moyen que partir d'un exposé lexicographique ; de plus, il ne s'agit pas strictement d'une copie mais d'une réécriture dans laquelle les informations de source sont éliminées et les exemples bien détachés les uns de autres de façon à améliorer la lecture.